# My .eu domain name was stolen. What are my options?

Tags: european-union, trademark, domain-name, cybersquatting

I have a company in a small European country, with a short, simple, generic name, say Generic, pvt. ltd.

For many years, I've had the domain generic.eu

However, I forgot to change my owner email address for generic.eu - over time, this email expired.

Recently, someone from a neighboring country acquired the expired email and gained control of generic.eu on eurid, thereby grabbing domain transfer code, and ultimately transferring the domain to himself, with a different registrar.

His actions are illegal right? Since my company name is Generic, pvt ltd, therefore "generic" is my trademark and I have a right to generic.eu correct, especially since I have owned the domain for many years...

How do I get my domain back? Can I make a claim for compensation for business lost due to this illegal grab of my domain?

Comment: Since you failed to renew the domain, you have lost it. https://eurid.eu/en/register-a-eu-domain/rules-for-eu-domains/

Comment: Well, it didn't expire. It was still live. Someone acquired the contact email (which had lapsed) and used that email to snipe the domain.

Comment: Have you looked at the WHOIS entry? https://www.eurodns.com/de/whois-suche/eu-domain Is it still in your name? What has your provider said?

Comment: Yeah, by acquiring the lapsed contact address, they managed to obtain the authorization code from eurid and registered the domain with a different registrar. whois now has their name/details as owner.

Comment: Then I think you have lost it. They probably tried to renew contacting you at the address given. When that failed assumed abandoned.

Comment: Again, the domain under question was not lapsed/expired at all. The email given as owner contact had lapsed.

Comment: If you registered the domain, including the fee, with your provider that hosted the domain then you should asked them for clarification. If they consider it still yours, then they may be able to report this (with proof) that the domain has be hijacked/stolen.